# FluentValidation is not working in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, validation, oop, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to validate input parameter for my endpoints. I want to use FluentValidator and here is the logic

```
// This class is in in different assembly than Program.cs class
public class EIdLoginDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<EIdLoginDto>
{
    #region Constructors
    public EIdLoginDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.EIdToken)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Some message");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then I do a registration of FluentValidator in Program.cs class like this:

```
builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<EIdLoginDtoValidator>();
```

However when I debug my app breakpoint goes to EIdLoginDtoValidator which is good, but even EIdToken is null program executiong goes to endpoint.
What I am doing wrong?
I have installed FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="11.2.2" and I've using .net 8.

Comment: Are you using an MVC approach or minimal API?

Answer (score 0):

The FluentValidation.AspNetCore package is no longer being maintained. Check the [link](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation.AspNetCore). So "AddFluentValidationAutoValidation" will not work. And on the fluentvalidation.net (the one you should use now) the automatic validation works only with ASP.NET, running on .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5 or .NET 6. Check the [link](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/).

> For automatic validation with ASP.NET, FluentValidation supports ASP.NET running on .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5 or .NET 6.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So what is workaround? What can I use instead of FluentValidation?